# FileUpload in DataLIst

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, datalist

I have datalist. Each item consists of FileUpload control.
How can I check the uploaded file after each upload?

Because I didn't know that, I tried to do something else - the check will be implemented after button click.

Note: this datalist is child of other datalist. This is nested datalist. The datasource of the parent is arraylist of orders, and the child's datasource is the products list in each order.

```
 private void UploadProduct(DataListItem dli, ArrayList pl) // pl = productsList
{
    int i = 0;
    DataList DataList2 = (DataList)dli.FindControl("DataList2");
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList2.Items)
    {
        Product p = pl[i] as Product;
        FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("FileUpload1");
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "" && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.Contains("jpg") && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 2097151)
        {
            p.UploadedProduct = FileUpload1.FileBytes; // pc.UploadedProduct is byte[]
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

In the Item_Command:

```
    if (e.CommandName == "finishOrder")
    {
        ArrayList ordersList = (ArrayList)Session["OrdersList"]; // the datasource of the outer datalist

        int orderID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        ProductsCart pc = null;
        foreach (ProductsCart productsCart in ordersList) // to get the object which the button refers to
        {
            if (productsCart.OrderID == orderID)
                pc = productsCart;

        }

        DataListItem item = ((DataListItem)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer); // to get the datalist item of the clicked button
        FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)(item.FindControl("FileUpload1"));
      //  Label errorMsg = (Label)(item.FindControl("errorMsg"));



        bool flag = true;
       // string imagePath;

        UploadProduct(item, pc.ProductsList);

        foreach (Product p in pc.ProductsList) // the check if the uploads were uploaded according to my conditions
        {
            if (p.UploadedProduct==null)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else // error
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('error');", true);
        }

        FillDataListOuter(DataList1); // datasource and databind   
    }
```

This is not working, thats why I ask for help. When I try to upload docx file it tries to execute the code if flag is true. So I guess this is not a good way to do it.
I need help, because I tried to read a lot and I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: check this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-bind-images-from-folder-to.html

Comment: But I want to make sure that what is uploaded satisfy the condition: (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "" && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.Contains("jpg") && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 2097151)